# Movie name from pictures. What Am I?

Tags: rebus

Identify my name from these pictures.[image]

Comment: @Wu33o  Hi you both wrote right answer(few seconds difference in time). But i cannot mark both your answers as correct. So I will mark  those who got highest votes till the end of today.

Comment: @oleslaw  pls check my comment

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The movie is:

> [Catch me if you can](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0264464/?ref_=nv_sr_1)

First image:

> Me

Second image:

> Can

Third image:

> Catch

Fourth image:

> If

Fifth image:

> You

If you change the order of the words, you get the movie mentioned in the first spoiler.

Comment: Oh, now I learned tin box of coke called "can".

Comment: @SonerGönül Yes! Other metal things shaped like that are also called cans. A **can** of vegetables, a **can** of tuna, the **Can**-**Can**...

Answer (score 17):

The movie title is

> Catch me if you can!

However it is worth noting that the images are not displayed in this order.

1st image:

> me

2nd image:

> can

3rd image:

> catch

4th image:

> if

5th image:

> you

Comment: So it's not in order?

Comment: @greenturtle3141 You have to change the order of the images to get the name correctly

Comment: @greenturtle3141 It is in the order of movie's motive.

Comment: Motive? I never watched it, oh well. (Also, why is the other answer getting more upvotes if this technically came first?)

Comment: @ManojKumar How so? Its one of my favorite movies and I'm trying to find out how it's in the order of the motive...perhaps that's part of the puzzle too?

Comment: @ManojKumar Care to explain the *movie's motive* regarding the order of images?

Comment: I commented that on the question and it was a big spoiler. I think the mods deleted it.

Comment: @ManojKumar I believe it is ok if you post your own answer with full explanation of the title **and** the ordering of the images - which is the complete answer neither of us succeeded in posting.

Comment: I believe that the word you are looking for is motif, not motive.