# Movie name from pictures(puzzle-2). What am I?

Tags: rebus

Unlike [puzzle-1](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46362/movie-name-from-pictures-what-am-i)  some words can be derived using [homophone](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/homonym-homophone-homograph/).

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The name of the movie is:

> **[I Still Know What You Did Last Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Still_Know_What_You_Did_Last_Summer)**

So let's see what we have here:

> **I**-Eye
>  **Still**- Steel(Still) or the cogs are dismantled and cannot move hence *Still*(Thanks @M Oehm for this)
>  **Know** - The boy in the image knows (Thanks @Lukas for this)
>  **What** - James Watt so Watt -> What
>  **You** - Fingers pointing towards you
>  **Did** - Shown in the image
>  **Last** - Last in the queue
>  **Summer** - The Sun

Comment: "Know" is probably: Student putting his hand up because he knows the answer to the question. Not sure about the gears...

Comment: The gear part is confusing. I think this is the expected answer. Let's wait for the Op's response. +1

Comment: I thought may be Nobelium(NO) is used for making gears. Turns out its radio active :D

Comment: Perhaps "[I Still Know What You Did Last Summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Still_Know_What_You_Did_Last_Summer)"? The cogs are dismantled, so they can't move; they are still. (Yes, that's a stretch, but eight images seem to hint at a title with eight words.)

Comment: @MOehm- Perfect. Let me edit.

Comment: @MOehm- I guess its just Steel(for still) considering homophones are used.

Comment: Yes, that's more plausible, although I don't really consider still and steel to be homophones of each other. (Okay, they are close enough, I guess.)